# Python--why T2 equal T1 after T1 append new value

Tags: python, append

```
T1 = (1,[5],3)
T2 = T1
print("T2 :",T2)
T1[1].append(6)
print("T1 :",T1)
print("T2 :",T2)

result：
T2 : (1, [5], 3)
T1 : (1, [5, 6], 3)
T2 : (1, [5, 6], 3)
```

when `T1` append new value, why `T2` equals to `T1`?
I think `T1 = (1,[5,6],3)` and `T2 = (1, [5], 3)`,  but finally `T2 is (1,[5,6],3)`

Comment: Because, they both are same object. You need to copy one to other: `T2 = copy.deepcopy(T1)`.

Comment: this answer may help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/)

Answer (score 0):

The line `T2 = T1` has the effect of binding the name `T2` to the same object as what `T1` is already bound to.

(It isn't creating a copy of the object)

This is true for any assignment statement in Python of the from `<LeftName> = <RightName>`.

This means, any modification done by your code, using the name `T1`, can be seen using the name `T2`, and vice versa.